# How do it disable message "double on tap" in view using talkback accessibility android?

Tags: android, accessibility

When a view  has event click  and enable talkback. I need to disable the audio "double to tap" in the view.

I am using accessibility in android development.

How can I do this, please?

Comment: Do you mean the "Double tap to activate" that TalkBack calls out for clickable elements? There's probably no good way to disable this - why would you want to? It's there to let a user know that the control is interactive, and not say static non-clickable text.

Comment: Hi, there is a possible way to disable the accessibility on the android views, like as:

`android:importantForAccessibility = "no" `

Comment: @fah127 Great. Thx

Answer (score 15):

If you check google talkback source code at [this](https://github.com/google/talkback/blob/master/compositor/src/main/res/raw/compositor.json#L1723) line and [here](https://github.com/google/talkback/blob/master/compositor/src/main/res/raw/compositor.json#L1764), string resource ("double tap") has been used [here](https://github.com/google/talkback/blob/master/compositor/src/main/res/raw/compositor.json#L1776) and [here](https://github.com/google/talkback/blob/master/compositor/src/main/res/raw/compositor.json#L1776)

So, you should remove `AccessibilityActionCompat.ACTION_CLICK` action and set `isClickable` to `false` in node info.

```
ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(view, object : AccessibilityDelegateCompat() {
        override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host: View, info: AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat) {
            super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info)
            info.removeAction(AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.AccessibilityActionCompat.ACTION_CLICK)
            info.isClickable = false
        }
    })
```

I tested this and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for this! I spent the last 3 days trying to solve a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(view, new AccessibilityDelegateCompat() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View host, AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat info) {
            super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info);
            info.addAction(AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_FOCUS);
        }
});
```

See more detail at https://stackoverflow.com/a/47875696/1915831

Answer (score 0):

Kiran's answer was really helpful, but still some of my devices were adding "double tap and hold to long press" or etc. I just wanted to read my whole paragraph and add "Double tap to activate" only. So I wrote like this;

```
ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(<YOUR_TEXTVIEW>, object : AccessibilityDelegateCompat() {
            override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host: View, info: AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat) {
                super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info)
                info.removeAction(AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.AccessibilityActionCompat.ACTION_CLICK)
                info.isClickable = false
                info.isLongClickable = false
                info.text = "${<YOUR_TEXTVIEW>.text}\n" + "Double tap to activate."
                host.isLongClickable = false
            }
        })
```

Answer (score -2):

For disabling you need to use `setClickable(false)`.
!!!And if you use `setOnClickListener()` on the View, audio "double to tap" will appears again