# How to change Talkback announces Press Alt + Shift + Enter to activate on Google map marker

Tags: android, google-maps, talkback, accessibility

I have a Google map and added marker on the map. When the accessibility mode is ON and we navigate to Map marker using Bluetooth keyboard it announces press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>⇧Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> to activate. However pressing the key combination does not have any action on map. How can i disable map marker to stop announcing this. I have overriden <kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> key and added my functionality on tap of Enter button. How can i change talkback to announce press <kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> instead of press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>⇧Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> to activate on map marker.

I have tried solution provided in [How to change Android talkback instructions for double tap and long press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39455917/how-to-change-android-talkback-instructions-for-double-tap-and-long-press)
and added delegate on `mapfragment.getView()` however `accessibility.getActionList` always is blank.

Some help will be appreciated Thanks.

Comment: I am facing the same issue in my Application. Did you solve this?

Comment: Not yet looks like an OS specific issue. I am waiting if someone can answer this, trying https://www.novoda.com/blog/alternative-interfaces/ this did not help as well. may be Accessibility Service is a solution but i want to do it without Accessibility Service.

Comment: I solved this by interrupting talkback and announcing my announcement using TTS