# Replace the whole announcemnt for "double tap to activate when talkback enabled

Tags: android, accessibility

After enabling Talkback and clicking one of the elements view in my app, the announcement is reciting:

The description that I included, pauses, then it recites: **"double tap to activate"**.

I used Accessibility delegate from the example that I found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39480983/5544859

But it's only replacing the last word for me instead of the whole sentence.

For example, it's saying: Bla Bla bla. (pauses), then double tap to **"custom string"**

I would like to replace the whole sentence.

Answer (score 4):

This phrase is coming from TalkBack and is not configurable by design. TalkBack is trying to provide a consistent user experience across all apps.

Comment: I love how the person working on this in Google gets downvoted... classic StackOverflow... Thanks for all your hard work Phil!

Comment: Is this a solution to OP's question?

Comment: he's downvoted because he's making an assumption that other developers won't have a use-case to NOT hear "double tap to". Developers want freedom. Here's one such use-case: There's a list of images, which can be selected. Selecting an image again has no use - is a wasted click. Now talkback tells the user "double tap to activate"... yeah, sure it's still clickable so why not ...  and nothing happens when clicked.